# jquery ajax variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, post

I'm stuck since 2 weeks, since i decided to use a nice threeview based on the jquery library.
My problem is what i'm trying to get the value of an selected folder as an variable to php.

I'm able to get the value and show it via an Alertbox in Jquery but the value is not posted to the PHP variable. echo shows nothing.

### Text under is just to clarify why i need to use this solution with php and so on.

Then this is solved i will keep on struggling to get the whole path that i later will send to a bash script what is already finished. It creates a text file with metatags from an flac or mp3 album for my SQL db already done and working. This app is local for maintainance of the database.

To my problem and code (bear in min what jquery and ajax is totally new for my)

filename: file_browser.php
Jquery part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var dir = ($(".active").text())
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"file_browser.php",
            data: dir,
            success: function(data){ 
            alert(dir); dir }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    echo "<form>
          <button>Append</button>
          <div id'japp'>";
    if (isset($_POST['dir'])) {
        $dir = $_POST['dir']; }
        echo $dir;
       echo "</div> 
              </form>"; 
?>
```

I will keep on trying, now i at leasthave an chance to get some help to avoid taking one more week on this :).

Comment: Shouldn't data in $.ajax be an array or object containing the variable names and values, not a single string?

Comment: I'm sorry for the format on the code i tried to indent code with 4 spaces. the result tells me what i obviously must have done it totally wrong.

Comment: Frank, it can be, but its not neccesary

Comment: Yeah after asking the question, I did what the OP probably should've done. I went to the jquery website and looked up the documentation. See my answer below.

Comment: I have search the net to learn about things that you have told me.

I'm unshure about my choise of variable name dir, does it already have an function reserved for dir objects? I don't know if the filethree i use in my browser and shows it like dirs and paths, if it treats dirs just like a real dirs on the computer or if the text value i use with .active and text is treated as an normal variable.

I must say one thing i honestly really apreciate the help and time you have given me and the answers i have reciewed have led me in a direction that have been very useful and teaching.

Comment: I bought myself a jQuery book to reduce my lack of understanding of terminology. I have read 3 chapters now and have almost solved the problem that was next on the list after variable to PHP.

Comment: Solution Data Option: var dir = ($(".active").parent('li').text());
Gives me the path visible on webpage(filestructure) unfortunatly also the hole url of my site but this can in worst case be solved with an regex if i'm not able to find the way to get the path without website url. 

I'll continue to read to understand the object way as you suggested for posting value of path to PHP variable. 

Once it's solved if i'm first, i show the solution here to help others with similar problem.

Comment: Hurray! finally, i have solved it. There is the best place to show my solution, in this comment or under answer?

Answer (score 2):

From the jquery website on [$.ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> By default, Ajax requests are sent using the GET HTTP method. If the
>   POST method is required, the method can be specified by setting a
>   value for the type option. This option affects how the contents of the
>   data option are sent to the server. POST data will always be
>   transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset, per the W3C
>   XMLHTTPRequest standard.
>
> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted
>   into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This
>   processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The
>   processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to
>   the server; in this case, change the contentType option from
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

I'm assuming the value of $(".active").text() is just the value you want to pass without any key paired to it. Format your string in a key/value pairs as shown above and you should be great.

Comment: Sorry for my late respond Frank. I'm suprised about how fast i reciewed so many answers. I'm reading your text carfully to make sure what i understand everything. 

About the value you wondered about: I'm not familiar to key value pairing yet, i'm reading about it now from the documentation you gave me. 
The value i want to send to php is the string of the selected dir fex. "Iron Maiden" it will later be the whole dir but it will be a problem to fix after this passing of string to php variable is solved.

Comment: To make a string containing key value pairs you just need to use the following line of code:


var dir = "dir="+$(".active").text();


That line of code will get the value, pass it in the post variable 'dir', and your php should work as it's  written. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Also a key pair value is anytime you associate a specific key, in this case 'dir', with a specific value, again in this case 'Iron Maiden'. Associative arrays and the querystring you see when using the GET HTTP method are both examples of key/pair values in programming.

Comment: After changing to  var dir = "dir="+$(".active").text();
The result of alert box string is "dir=Iron Maiden".
PHP is still empty.

Comment: Then I would recommend trying the object approach as found in the other two answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your `$_POST` array to contain a `dir` element, you need to send a key - value pair to your script:

```
var dir = { "dir": $(".active").text() };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        // setting a key-value
        var dir = { dir: $(".active").text() };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"file_browser.php",
            data: dir,
            success: function(data){ 
            alert(dir);} //removed the second 'dir'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried your suggestion.
Original code gave the output of the dir via alert fex. the dirname of the artist. The php echo was empty.
Your code gave: alertbox object Object: PHP echo still empty.

Comment: is it possible that `$(".active")` matches more than 1 elements? What does `console.log($(".active"));` say?

Comment: I'm not shure how to use console.log but if i understood it correct the firebug shows after i added console.log to my code.

Comment: Source Album Name
Same name in parameter as source :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var dir = ($(".active").text()); // from my question (gives name of selected dir)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file_browser.php",
            data: { dir: "dir" },
            success: function(response){ // function(response) was (data)
            $('#japp').html(dir);        // points to the forms id="japp"
            alert(dir); }
        });
    });
});
```

Question above solved.

My other mentioned problem
Getting full path instead of just dir. Partly solved.

Gives the hole path as string with dir (wanted) + the dir one more time (not wanted).
It also gives website url i think instead of root (/) (not wanted) + visible path on webpage from filesystem (wanted).

This can be solved with an regex in php but i will first try to make it cleaner by getting only the wanted stuff with this jQuery function.

Left my almost done solution here just to give a hint there to begin if needed.

```
var dir = ($(".active").parent('li').text());
```

Thanks for all help and for leading me on the right way @Frank B, @jeroen & @Zim84